# Displaying percentage in ttk progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to display percentage in `ttk.Progressbar` when the function is running to alert the user the extent of the process performed and what is left. Am able to display the percentage all right but the percentage is up to `23%` which is the `length`  of my `tuple`.

How can I make it to reach 100% with the same `length` of `tuple`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time


tuple_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
brt = len(tuple_1)

def progress_bar_func():
    num = 0
    for item in range(brt):  # THIS
        print(item)
        num += 1  # THIS MEANS ADDING ONE TO THE PREVIOUS VALUE
        progressBar['value'] = num
        # THIS UPDATING TEXT IN PROGRESSBAR WITH PERCENTAGE
        style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
                        text='{:g} %'.format(item))
        root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

# THIS STYLE FOR THE PROGRESSBAR
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
             [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
               {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                              {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                'sticky': 'nswe'}),
              ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
              # ,lightcolor=None,bordercolo=None,darkcolor=None
style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0 %')

progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(root,style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', length=200,  maximum=brt, value=0,)
progressBar.pack()

progress_button = tk.Button(root, text="start", command=progress_bar_func)
progress_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of progressbar]

Comment: It's just math - if the value is 23 and the max is 24, the percentage is 23/24.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay i thought i could make it upto `100` by the way thanks.

Comment: Bryan's comment IS how you make it up to `100`. You need to find the fraction that you have done, which is the number of items processed over the total items that need processing. This will give you a number between `0` and `1`. Multiply that by `100` to get the percentage.

Comment: When it hits 24, 24/24 = 1. 1 == 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bryan Oakley and others pointed out the solution is mainly do the math correctly. Here's a concrete example of doing that based on the code in your question. I also modified it to demonstrate the `Progressbar` working in what I think is a slightly better fashion — namely by using the universal [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) function to periodically update the bar's value.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

tuple_1 = tuple(range(1, 25))

def progress_bar_func(style, progress_bar, sequence):
    root.after(500, update_progress_bar, style, progress_bar, 1, len(sequence))

def update_progress_bar(style, progress_bar, num, limit):
    if num <= limit:
        percentage = round(num/limit * 100)  # Calculate percentage.
        progress_bar.config(value=num)
        style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='{:g} %'.format(percentage))
        num += 1
        root.after(500, update_progress_bar, style, progress_bar, num, limit)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
             [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
               {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                              {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                'sticky': 'nswe'}),
              ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0 %')

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', length=200,
                               maximum=len(tuple_1), value=0)
progress_bar.pack()

progress_button = tk.Button(root, text="start",
                            command=lambda: progress_bar_func(style, progress_bar, tuple_1))
progress_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of `Progressbar` upon completion:

[image: screenshot of progressbar when it stops updating]

Comment: the style used `text.Horizontal.TProgressbar`... Where can we find the list of all such allowed styles and their respective configuration?

Also, I was using bar.Hori...etc with its background, foreground, troughcolor, etc arguments. Now, when I replace that with text.Hori...etc it doesn't change the colors anymore. Does it not have those arguments?

What if I also want to change the color of the bar and also add test to the bar?