# How to display text in two different Progressbars with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, styles, progress-bar

I have a window with two different `Progressbar`s. I want to add different text information over them (i.e. "88/1524" on the first one and "88/10000" on the second).
I've found a solution for one `Progressbar` on this question: [Displaying percentage in ttk progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918648/displaying-percentage-in-ttk-progressbar)

However it uses a style modification workaround to add text on the progress bar, and as I understand it, the style attribute `text.Horizontal.TProgressbar` is shared for all progress bars. This means I can't have a different text on each progress bar. When I need to update the text, I don't know how to target one specific progress bar.

Is there any other way to do it, or am I missing something?
Can I instantiate the label to have something like `text.Horizontal.TProgressbar1` and `text.Horizontal.TProgressbar2`?

Here's my current setup without labels:
[image: Progressbars]

Where I'm stuck at:
[image]

And portion of my code:

```
style = tkinter.ttk.Style(root)

style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', 
            [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
            {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                            {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                'sticky': 'nswe'}), 
            ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0/0')

ProgressBarOfDirectory = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(ProgressbarFrame,
                                                 style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
                                                 orient="horizontal",
                                                 length=WidthOfElements,
                                                 mode="determinate",
                                                 maximum=NbStepOfProgressBar,
                                                 variable=PourcentageOfDirectoryAnalysisDone)
ProgressBarOfDirectory.pack(side="top")

ProgressBarOfAll = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(ProgressbarFrame,
                                           style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
                                           orient="horizontal",
                                           length=WidthOfElements,
                                           mode="determinate",
                                           maximum=NbStepOfProgressBar,
                                           variable=PourcentageOfAllAnalysisDone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget styles aren't shared unless the same one it specified for more than one widget (or the same default one gets assigned to more than one because something else wasn't specified).

To take advantage of that here's an updated version of the code to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922734/355230) to that other question. In order to ensure the independence of the each `Progressbar` instance, it derives a new class from the built-in `ttk.Progressbar` which creates a separate style object for each instance created.

Below is the code along with a runnable demo at the end.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyProgressBar(ttk.Progressbar):
    _inst_count = 0  # Number of class instances created.

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        classname = type(self).__name__
        assert 'style' not in kwargs, \
               f'{classname} initializer does not support providing a ttk "style".'
        type(self)._inst_count += 1  # Increment class attribute.
        # Create a style with a different name for each instance.
        self.style = ttk.Style(root)
        self.stylename = f'text.Horizontal.TProgressbar{self._inst_count}'
        self.style.layout(self.stylename,
                          [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
                            {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                                           {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                             'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                           ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
        maximum = kwargs['maximum']
        self.style.configure(self.stylename, text=f'0/{maximum}')
        kwargs.update(style=self.stylename)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    DELAY1 = 100
    DELAY2 = 25
    MAX1 = 1524
    MAX2 = 10000

    def progress_bar_func(delay, progress_bar):
        # Start periodic progress-bar update process.
        maximum = progress_bar.cget('maximum')
        style = progress_bar.style  # Progressbar must have a style attribute.
        root.after(delay, update_progress_bar, delay, style, progress_bar, 1, maximum)

    def update_progress_bar(delay, style, progress_bar, num, maximum):
        if num <= maximum:
            progress_bar.config(value=num)
            style.configure(progress_bar.stylename, text=f'{num}/{maximum}')
            num += 1
            root.after(delay, update_progress_bar, delay, style, progress_bar, num, maximum)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")

    progress_bar1 = MyProgressBar(root, length=200, maximum=MAX1, value=0)
    progress_bar1.pack()
    progress_bar2 = MyProgressBar(root, length=200, maximum=MAX2, value=0)
    progress_bar2.pack()

    def start_progress_bars():
        progress_bar_func(DELAY1, progress_bar1)
        progress_bar_func(DELAY2, progress_bar2)

    progress_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start_progress_bars)
    progress_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Here's a couple of screenshots of it running:

[image: screenshots of it running]

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar doesn’t have a feature to display text on its own.

What you could do is to use a Label widget. All you have to do is to place a Label widget where ever you want to implement the text.

Now you can configure the text value of the label & can change it with the change in the Python Tkinter progress bar.

Here you can find an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time


def step():
    for i in range(5):
        ws.update_idletasks()
        pb['value'] += 20
        time.sleep(1)
        txt['text']=pb['value'],'%'

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('200x150')
ws.config(bg='#345')


pb = Progressbar(
    ws,
    orient = HORIZONTAL,
    length = 100,
    mode = 'determinate'
    )

pb.place(x=40, y=20)

txt = Label(
    ws,
    text = '0%',
    bg = '#345',
    fg = '#fff'

)

txt.place(x=150 ,y=20 )

Button(
    ws,
    text='Start',
    command=step
).place(x=40, y=50)

ws.mainloop()
```