# Formatting Text to the Tkinter Progressbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I got to know about adding the text to the progress bar as per this question:

[Displaying percentage in ttk progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918648/displaying-percentage-in-ttk-progressbar/58922734?noredirect=1#comment124404166_58922734)

It helps me but I need a few more adjustments to do to the answer.

1. I need the text (the percentage) to appear on the left side of the progressbar.

   For this, I added `'side':'left'` to the layout format for `Horizontal.TProgressbar.label`.

As under:

```
style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
    [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
    {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
    {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
    'sticky': 'nswe'}),
    ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'side':'left','sticky': ''})])
```

However, this moves the text to extreme left. It overlaps the progressbar border and is not clearly readable.

2. I need to adjust the font and font color of this text. How do we change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To change the space between the label and the border you can add a padding element to the layout

   ```
    style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
        [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
          {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                         {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
           'sticky': 'nswe'}),
         ('Horizontal.Progressbar.padding', {'side':'left'}),
         ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'side':'left','sticky': ''})])
   ```

   Then configure the padding with

   ```
   style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', padding=4)
   ```
2. You can change the font and color of the text using `style.configure` with the `font` and `foreground` options:

   ```
    style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', foreground="red", font='Arial 20')
   ```

There is a full example of creating such a progressbar in my answer to [Progressbar with Percentage Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896881/progressbar-with-percentage-label/47902046).

Comment: This sticky west and side methods moves the text too much to the left almost on the border. Making it unreadable. Can we keep some distance from the border and where the text starts? Or only solution is to add space before the text?

Comment: @Meet I now realized that I was not answering the first part of the question properly. I have now found a way to add some padding and edited my answer.

Comment: Hey! Thanks this worked. Btw, how exactly are you creating that layout? I can't find any help or article on how to work with that syntax.

Comment: @Meet I don't remember really, I have learned the syntax for the layout from examples, mostly on SO and by trying things on my own. You can look at the layout of existing elements with `style.layout(<name>)` where `<name >` is "TLabel", "TFrame", ...  You can get a list of elements to use in layouts with `style.element_names()` and their options with `style.element_options(<element name>)`.